# Training and validation loss and accuracy in lstm

Tags: python, nlp

I am doing text classification with 3 classes, after dealing with over fit model, the image below is my model accuracy and loss results after adding regulization l2, now it means my models is learning ?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're dealing with an overfit even after you've added the L2 regularization.
Your model is not learning much after the third epoch.
Some solutions you should consider:

- Increasing the value of your L2 regularization
- Decreasing the number of weights in your model, to support your dataset size
- Increasing your dropout regularization amount
- Transfer learning from a different classification task (for example, you can pre-train your model to classify news articles in your language to different categories)
- Increase the size of your dataset with data augmentations

Good Luck!